# Any Way to Maintain Data Consistency among Modules?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, synchronization, consistency

Usually if we have many resources which owned by single module and modified by many threads and we want to keep data consistency among these threads, one way to do that is using locks.

But this seems impossible when resources are distributed into several modules. For example, suppose we have three modules, they are **SocketsLayer, SessionLayer, FileTransferLayer**. And some other asumptions:

1. **SocketsLayer**
   Maintain all (non-blocking) sockets;
   Use one thread to listen and read from sockets;
   Use same thread to delete sockets when closed and notify **SessionLayer** asynchronously.
2. **SessionLayer**
   Create a session for each user;
   Each user has one socket called CmdChannel for send/recv commands;
   Each user has several sockets called DataChannel for send/recv file data;
   Each (username, cmd socket, data sockets) is called a **session**.
   Once socket is registered as CmdChannel for USER, session for this user is created.
   Once CmdChannel is closed or broken, Session which owns it became invalid (BE DELETED).
   Once Session became invalid, all data sockets became invalid.
   Use one thread to create session and delete session.
3. **FileTransferLayer**
   Each user has several file transfer tasks;
   Each file transfer task has its own data socket;
   All tasks belong to one user share one command socket;
   Once the user's session became invalid, tasks belong to this user must be deleted.
   Use one thread to create tasks and delete tasks.

Suppose one cmd channel is being registered for **SomeUser** (handled by **SessionLayer**), now **SessionLayer** is going to create a **session** for this user. But what if this cmd socket is closed by peer during the period the **session** is being created?

**UPDATE**
**Sockets** in **SocketsLayer** and **session** in **SessionLayer** and **tasks** in **FileTransferLayer**, all these three types of data belong to the same user must keep consistent. But they are owned by different modules, so how to maintain data consistency among these three modules?

Comment: Aside: It's generally a good idea to `shutdown` a socket rather than `close` it. This leaves you with a valid handle which will fail reads and writes - which the code using the socket can easily detect - rather than an invalid handle. You then defer the `close` until the code using it has noticed.